# Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic such that $|f(z)|<M$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic such that $|f(z)|<M$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ prove that f is a constant function.

How do you prove this problem because here $f$ is just holomorphic so we can't apply Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Why can't you apply [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) ?

Comment: @lhf......I am think f is holomorphic but not entire so ..

Answer (score 4):

You have **exactly** the conditions of Liouville's theorem. Your function is holomorphic in all $\mathbb{C}$ (which means entire) and bounded, hence it is constant.